# How to execute from action="third party location" from validation script PHP/ jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

I'am developing a payment form. This form has an action attribute, to send form data to epay. The problem is that I need to validate this form data before sending it to epay. Is there some way that I can execute the form action from the validation script instead?

The form id is being used to catch the form submit using jQuery, and start validating the data.

```
<form id="ajax-payment-form" action="url to payment company site">
```

Thanks for your time

Troels

Answer (score 0):

The normal way you do this is by having your `submit` event handler return `false` (or calling `e.preventDefault();`) when the form is not valid, and *not* return `false` (or call `preventDefault`) if it is valid. By not cancelling the default action, you allow the form to be submitted.

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, you can use the form's `submit` function:

```
$("#ajax-payment-form")[0].submit();
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("ajax-payment-form").submit();
```

That will submit the form, *without* triggering any form submit handlers. (The theory there is that if you're submitting the form programmatically, you've already validated it.)

Note that I'm calling `submit` on the DOM element directly. If you use jQuery to do it (`$("#ajax-payment-form").submit();`), the submit event handlers *will* be called. Example *(Stack Snippets don't allow form submissions, so...)* [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ceyimo/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Note the onsubmit="return false;" to prevent form
       submission if the handler is triggered -->
  <form id="the-form" action="http://google.com/search" target="_blank" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="kittens">
  </form>
  <button id="via-jquery">Submit with jQuery</button>
  <button id="via-DOM">Submit with DOM</button>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    $("#via-jquery").on("click", function() {
      $("#the-form").submit();
    });
    $("#via-DOM").on("click", function() {
      $("#the-form")[0].submit();
    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your respond. When calling event.preventDefault(); after $("#ajax-payment-form").submit(function() { - the action is not executing, thats good :) but what function should i call when this validation is ok, and i want the action to be executed?

Comment: @thar: As I said above, either *don't* call `event.preventDefault()` (not calling it allows the form to be submitted after you've validated it), or call `submit` on the form element (within your `submit` handler, that would be: `this.submit();`&nbsp;&mdash; but again, there's no need, just don't prevent the default action when the form is valid).

Answer (score 0):

If you return `false` from within a submit handler the form won't submit.

```
$('#ajax-payment-form').submit(function(){
    var isValid= true;
    /* run validation code and set isValid = false if any conditions fail*/


    return isValid;
});
```